# Is App indexing possible in react native android app?

Tags: react-native, android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

Firebase App Indexing gets your app into Google Search. is there any way to implement firebase app indexing in react native app ?

Comment: Yes ! read detailed article [here](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e)

Comment: not a single mention of app indexing in the article.